# Converting C++ code to visual c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have done my project on image processing using opencv, however, it is completely command line oriented there is no GUI. Will it be too much of a task to convert my whole source code into GUI using Visual C++ [Windows Forms Applications] given that i only have about a week to submit my source code? If it can be done how should i go about it?

Comment: Windows Forms is a .NET API. It has very little to do with C++.

Comment: Give it a go! When you get stuck on a *specific* problem, we may be able to help.

Comment: @jalf : I edited the question to more clearly indicate what I _think_ the OP's intent is.

Comment: @ildjarn And if it wasn't? Please only edit people's posts if (1) you're sure what you're doing is correct, and (2) it is a change thate you know the OP agrees with. There's a *huge* difference between "I have some C++ code I want to write some GUI for, and someone mentioned WinForms", and "I'd like to rewrite my code in C++/CLI so that I can use WinForms". In the former case, the answer might well be "use another GUI technology". And, uh, since this seems to be a school project, Rewriting in another language probably won't be acceptable, assuming this was a C++ project.

Comment: @jalf : If you want to explain the mechanism to use C++ code with WinForms _without_ C++/CLI, or give an alternative meaning for `Visual C++ [Windows Forms Applications]`, then be my guest. I stand behind my edit.

Comment: @ildjarn: I already gave an explanation: the OP is/was not aware that WinForms are not accessible from plain C++. But even so, you're the one making the edit, the burden of proof is on you. I don't need to provide proof positive of what the OP meant. You do.

Comment: If I asked a question about how to compile my C++ source code with a Java compiler, would you also just edit my question into asking how to compile Java code with a Java compiler?

Comment: The title of the question talked about converting from "C++" to "Visual C++". That tells me that the OP is not aware of the difference between C++, Visual C++ and C++/CLI. And so, editing the question into a question of converting from C++ to C++/CLI is just wrong

Comment: @jalf : Visual C++ plus WinForms equals C++/CLI. Once you're done ranting, you may consider this very simple logic.

Comment: @ildjarn: Logic? Your definition of "logic" is very different from mine. C++ is a language. WinForms is an API which is accessible from CLR languages. C++ does not use the CLR, thus C++ and WinForms are not compatible. Visual C++ is an IDE and a compiler. The OP asked a question that is strictly speaking nonsensical. But even so, nowhere did it mention C++/CLI, and yet you happily changed his question int one about how to convert C++ code to C++/CLI.

Comment: @jalf : "*The OP asked a question that is strictly speaking nonsensical.*" No, the OP asked a question that is _naive_. Visit the MSDN VC++ forums some time -- **no one** who asks questions there knows the difference between C++ and C++/CLI. As a Visual C++ MVP, I see naive questions like this on a daily basis on said forums, and consequently **years** of experience tells me that any mention of VC++ plus WinForms is simply by someone who doesn't know how to differentiate between the language and the IDE. I stand by my edit, just not enough to edit it back and continue this petty argument.

Comment: @ildjarn: yes, it is naive, but that perhaps you should read what I said. Strictly speaking, C++ is a language and Visual C++ is an IDE. Therefore, strictly speaking, asking how to convert from C++ to Visual C++ is nonsensical. Now, have you considered the other option? That this guy has to write a C++ program for a school project, and wants a GUI. And a quick Google or similar tells him that "WinForms" is the Microsoft way of doing a GUI. He sees that VS has a project type it describes as "Visual C++ Windows Forms", and he assumes that "I can use this from my C++ program".

Comment: By the way, I'm not impressed by your "years" of experience as a MVP on Microsoft's forums. Because it is *frightening* how bad answers people get to their questions there, and how frequently questions are misunderstood **not least by MVP's**. And no matter how many *decades* of experience you have, you are not exempt from the rules on SO, which state when editing, **clarify meaning without changing it**, and **always respect the original author**.

Comment: @jalf : And his assumption would be correct -- his program can remain a C++ program, and he can simply link it with a C++/CLI frontend. Do _you_ have any actual experience with C++/CLI? It certainly doesn't appear so.

Comment: @ildjarn: sure, or he could write a frontend in Python, end call into that. But given that this is a school project, and given that he didn't clearly say that "writing part of it in another language is ok", I think changing his question into "I want to write part of my program in another language" is unacceptable.

Comment: @jalf : Except that's what he said he __wanted__ to do, because he mentioned WinForms. On the one hand, you're criticizing the OP for asking a "non-sensical" question; on the other hand, you criticize attempts to reword the question into what the OP **obviously** intended to ask. If the issue here is simply that nothing makes you happy, then I'm completely okay with that. Certainly your strawman of attacking _answers_ on the MSDN forums, and the MVPs there, doesn't lend you any credibility, considering I said to read the _questions_ there and see that the OP's mistake is far from uncommon.

Comment: @jalf : "*By the way, I'm not impressed by your "years" of experience as a MVP on Microsoft's forums. Because it is frightening how bad answers people get to their questions there, and how frequently questions are misunderstood not least by MVP's.*" By the way, "perhaps you should read what I said" -- I said I've seen questions like this hundreds of times there; I wasn't claiming superiority of knowledge, only experience with naive questions. For someone who likes to criticize other people's reading comprehension, you could stand a bit of work in that area.

Answer (score 1):

It ultimately depends on how well you designed your existing code:

- If your logic is cleanly separated from any user I/O then using C++/CLI and WinForms is probably the **quickest** way to get a GUI implemented.
- However if your code is littered with e.g. `std::cout` with no separation of concerns, then you have quite a rewrite ahead regardless of which GUI framework you decide to use in the end.

I.e., aside from C++/CLI's learning curve (it is in fact a completely different language than C++), whether you use WinForms or something like Qt or wxWidgets for the GUI is mostly irrelevant -- getting all the console-oriented cruft out of your existing code is the time-consuming part.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends.

I don't know Windows Forms... but using a good library indeed (e.g. Qt) if what you need to do is showing for example an image and display some widgets for parameters or may be allowing some area selection it's something that can take even less than an hour to do.

However this assuming you know GUI programming and the library/framework.

Knowing nothing about either it may be much much harder unless you can find an already made example quite close to what you need.

Not knowing what the GUI is supposed to present the user it's quite hard to give an estimate...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for it!!

Save a copy as you have it and have a go! How quickly it will go depends on you, of course. It mostly comes down to how well structured your code is and how modular it is. For example, if your code is completely tied up with command line input then it'll be more difficult. If you need to make bits of code independent of the command line then I'd recommend doing that first, and then (save that copy again) GUI it up.

You will also have to choose your method of GUI (MFC, your own Win32 implementation, other people might have other suggestions there).